# Is these sequence present on OEIS?

Tags: number-theory, factorial, oeis

- Sequence one

Number which is equal to the product of the factorials of its digits.

- Sequence two

Factorial of a number is equal to the product of factorials of its digits.

Comment: Write some of  first terms in OEIS search line .

Comment: @Khosrotash I don't have terms

Comment: You write the definition , so you can write some terms ! can't you  ?

Comment: @Khosrotash No, he can't. The first and second elements of the sequence are 1 and 2, for both sequences. Can you write down the third one?

Comment: Hint: both sequences start with $1,2$.

Answer (score 4):

Sequence two is all the single digits and no others.  $10$ is too large and all other factorials will have a factor $11$ while the product of digit factorials will not.  I suspect sequence one is just $1,2$ but cannot prove it.  Note that you want the average base $10$ log of the digit factorials to be about $1$, so the number has to consist mostly of digits $0,1,2,3$.

Comment: +1 for the speculation that $1,2$  is the only solution ;-)

Comment: By exhaustive search, no other solution below a million.